# Trigger signal when file size limit is reached

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qfileinfo

I'm writing log files and would like to set a size limit of 10 Mo.

I was thinking of setting a `QTimer` triggering every X minutes/hours [QFileInfo::refresh](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#refresh) and checking the size of the file.

Would there be a better way to do this? Using a `QTimer` sounds painful and resource-costly to me. I wish I could use a `SIGNAL` when the limit size is reached.

Comment: Since your code is doing the writing, you can just keep a counter of the number of bytes you have written so far (add the number-of-bytes-just-written to it after each write).  After each write, check the counter to see if it just became larger than your threshold, and if it did, emit the signal.

Comment: This could be a solution. However, the writing part is done by a third-party library. I would llike to leave its code untouched. I only have access to the file.

Comment: However, I could check the size of the file each time I call the log function.

Comment: @GrégoireBorel _"...each time I call the log function"_ So, why don't you keep track of number of bytes you pass to this "log" function?

Answer (score 0):

Simple and working solution is to **read a file size** with `QFile::size()` **right after writing** to a log file and **react if the size exceeds** the limit. Note that the file must be opened when the size is read.

```
void Logger::log(const QString &rLine)
{
    QFile f(logFileName());
    if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&f);
        out << rLine << endl;
        qint64 f_size = f.size();
        f.close();
        checkFileSize(f_size);
    }
    else
    {
        QTextStream out(stdout);
        out << "CAN'T OPEN LOG FILE: " << logFileName();
    }
}

void Logger::checkFileSize(qint64 size)
{
    if (size <= maxFileSize())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Roll the log file or do whatever you wish like send a signal
}
```